# How to remove duplicate entries if they occur within a certain time frame in R

Tags: r, remove-if

I am trying to handle a database like the one below which has camera trap data.  There is no lag between photos being taken so ones that occur in quick succession are likely to be the same individual.

I want to remove duplicates of species if they occur within 10 minutes of eachother as they are likely to be the same individual. (ie if less that 10 minutes elapses between the last photo and the next one). Is there a way to do this in R? Thank you!

```
  Site.Name Sampling.Unit.Name Photo.Date Photo.Time   Genus Species Number.of.Animals
1 Ranomafana        CT-RNF-1-01 06/10/2010   00:01:00                                  
2 Ranomafana        CT-RNF-1-01 11/10/2010   00:28:00 Eliurus  tanala                 1
3 Ranomafana        CT-RNF-1-01 12/10/2010   04:39:22   Fossa fossana                 1
4 Ranomafana        CT-RNF-1-01 12/10/2010   04:39:27   Fossa fossana                 1
5 Ranomafana        CT-RNF-1-01 12/10/2010   16:47:41 Nesomys   rufus                 1
6 Ranomafana        CT-RNF-1-01 12/10/2010   16:47:46 Nesomys   rufus                 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps if you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, people would find it easier to answer. In your example, use `dput()` to paste your data into the question.

Comment: What database are you using?  "r" is not a database.  If the data is in "r", then the database tag should be removed.

Comment: Apologies, i am new to posting on this forum so still feeling my way with the formatting...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your `data.frame` with just the dates and times

```
 dat <- data.frame(Photo.Date =
 c("6/10/2010","11/10/2010","12/10/2010","12/10/2010","12/10/2010","12/10/2010"),
 Photo.Time = c("00:01:00","00:28:00","04:39:22","04:39:27","16:47:41","16:47:46"))
```

Then use `strptime` (strip time) to convert the dates into POSIX format

```
date_vec <-strptime(paste(dat$Photo.Date, dat$Photo.Time), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

The next step is to determine the difference in time between each observation. To do this you need to compare observation 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4...

```
first_date <- date_vec[1:(length(date_vec)-1)]
second_date <- date_vec[2:length(date_vec)]
second_gap <- difftime(second_date, first_date, units="mins")
```

Determine the gaps that are less than 10 minutes apart. You also need to add `TRUE` to keep the first time.

```
dup_index <- second_gap>10
dup_index <- c(TRUE, dup_index)
dat[dup_index, ]
```

Which returns

```
  Photo.Date Photo.Time
1  6/10/2010   00:01:00
2 11/10/2010   00:28:00
3 12/10/2010   04:39:22
5 12/10/2010   16:47:41
```

HTH